# How client should handle Host Name verification when multiple domains are present

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I have created a Public Cert for my server with **abc.com** and imported it into my clients trustore, But I'm using **cde.com** to invoke my application which resides on the server. **cde.com** resolves to **abc.com** with auto domain resolution (with a DNS). So my question is which hostname I should use for HostName verification. I think as per the specification [[1]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) I should use **cde.com** to do the verification. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The name as seen in the URL is the relevant one, i.e. DNS CNAME does not matter.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the quick response, So that means I need to consider cde.com, which is the initial URL going to initiate the connection?

Comment: From my understanding of your problem you are using DNS CNAME, i.e. set one domain as an alias for another one. This means that there is no *initial* URL but only a *single* URL from the perspective of the browser. This would be different when using a HTTP redirect because in this case multiple URLs would be seen by the browser. In any case: the certificates subject must always match the name in all URL's involved, i.e. the single URL if you use DNS CNAME and multiple URL's if you use HTTP redirect.